# How can I write a simple classifier and generate a merged dataframe from it

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation

I have a df like this;

```
>df[1:6,1:6]

>            ABT.263 ABT.869 ABT.888 AC220 Afatinib Afatinib.rescreen.
> BT-20          1       1       1     1        0                  1
> CAL-120        0       1       1     1        1                  1
> CAL-51         1       1       1     1        1                  1
> CAL-85-1       1       1       1     1        1                  0
> DU-4475        0       1       1     1        1                  1
> HCC1143        1       1       1     1        0                  1
```

Basically, I want to extract 1's and 0's of each column's row name. Then put them into adjacent columns in a loop form.

Desired output is like this;

```
> final_df[1:6,1:4]

>            ABT.263_1    ABT.263_0    ABT.869_1    ABT.869_0
>               BT-20       CAL-120      BT-20         NA
>               CAL-51      DU-4475      CAL-120
>               CAL-85-1                 CAL-51
>               HCC1143                  CAL-85-1
>                                        DU-4475
>                                        HCC1143
```

I can extract rownames of 0 cells and 1 cells separately with this;

```
  value1 <- rownames(df)[which(df[,1] == 1)]

  value0 <- rownames(df)[which(df[,1] == 0)]
```

However, failed to assign value1 and value0 vectors respectively in a df format with loops.

```
> dput(head(resp_tnbc, 20))
structure(list(ABT.263 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ABT.869 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ABT.888 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AC220 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Afatinib = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Afatinib.rescreen. = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), AG.014699 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AICAR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), AKTinhibitorVIII = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AMG.706 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AP.24534 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AR.42 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AS601245 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AS605240 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AT.7519 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ATRA = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AUY922 = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AV.951 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Axitinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), AZD6244 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), AZD6244.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AZD6482 = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), AZD6482.1 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AZD7762 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), AZD8055 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BAY61.3606 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bexarotene = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bicalutamide = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bicalutamide.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BIRB0796 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), BIX02189 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bleomycin = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bleomycin.50uM. = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMN.673 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMS.345541 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMS.536924.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMS.708163 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMS.708163.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BMS.754807 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bosutinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Bryostatin1 = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), BX.795 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), BX.912 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), CAL.101 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Camptothecin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CAY10603 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CCT007093 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CCT018159 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), CEP.701 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Cetuximab = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), CH5424802 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), CHIR.99021 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CHIR.99021.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CI.1040 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Cisplatin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CP466722 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CP724714 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CUDC.101 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), CX.5461 = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Cytarabine = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Dabrafenib = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), DMOG = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Docetaxel = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Doxorubicin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), EHT1864 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), EKB.569 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Elesclomol = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Embelin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), EpothiloneB = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Etoposide = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), EX.527 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), FH535 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), FK866 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FMK = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FR.180204 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), FTI.277 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GDC0941 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GDC0941.rescreen. = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Gefitinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Gemcitabine = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GenentechCpd10 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GSK.1904529A = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), GSK.650394 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GSK1070916 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), GSK2126458 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GSK269962A.1 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), GSK429286A = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), GSK690693 = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), GW.2580 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), GW441756 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), HG.6.64.1 = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), I.BET151 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), IOX2 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), IPA.3 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), JNJ.26854165 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), JNK.9L = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), JNKInhibitorVIII = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), JQ1 = c(1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), JQ1.1 = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), JQ12 = c(1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), JW.7.24.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.055 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.102 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.236 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.244 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.260 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.266 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KIN001.270 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), KU.55933 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), LAQ824 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Lenalidomide = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), LFM.A13 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), LY317615 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Masitinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Methotrexate = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Midostaurin = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), MitomycinC = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), MK.2206 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), MLN4924 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), MP470 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), MPS.1.IN.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NG.25 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Nilotinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NPK76.II.72.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NSC.207895 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NSC.87877 = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NU.7441 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Nutlin.3a = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NVP.BEZ235 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), NVP.BHG712 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ObatoclaxMesylate = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Olaparib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Olaparib.1 = c(1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), OSI.027 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), OSI.906 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), OSI.930 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), OSU.03012 = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PAC.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Pazopanib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PD.0325901 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), PD.0332991 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PD.173074 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), PF.4708671 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PF.562271 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), PFI.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PHA.793887 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Phenformin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), PI.103 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PIK.93 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), piperlongumine = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), PLX4720 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PLX4720.rescreen. = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PXD101.Belinostat = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), QL.X.138 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), QL.XI.92 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), QL.XII.47 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), QS11 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RDEA119 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RDEA119.rescreen. = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), RO.3306 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), rTRAIL = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), Ruxolitinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SB.505124 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SB.715992 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), SB216763 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SB52334 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), SB590885 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SGC0946 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), Shikonin = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SL0101.1 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SN.38 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SNX.2112 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), STF.62247 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), T0901317 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TAK.715 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Tamoxifen = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Temozolomide = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), Temsirolimus = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TG101348 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Thapsigargin = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), THZ.2.102.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), THZ.2.49 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Tipifarnib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TL.1.85 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TL.2.105 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TPCA.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Trametinib = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), TubastatinA = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UNC0638 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UNC0638.1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), UNC1215 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Vinblastine = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Vinorelbine = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Vismodegib = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), VNLG.124 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Vorinostat = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), VX.11e = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), VX.702 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), WZ3105 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X.5Z..7.Oxozeaenol = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X17.AAG = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X5.Fluorouracil = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), X681640 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), XAV939 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), XL.184 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), XL.880 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), XMD13.2 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), XMD14.99 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), XMD15.27 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Y.39983 = c(1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), YK4.279 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), YM155 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), YM201636 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Zibotentan.ZD4054 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ZM.447439 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ZSTK474 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c("BT-20", 
"CAL-120", "CAL-51", "CAL-85-1", "DU-4475", "HCC1143", "HCC1187", 
"HCC1395", "HCC1937", "HCC2157", "HCC38", "HDQ-P1", "Hs-578-T", 
"MDA-MB-231", "MDA-MB-436", "MDA-MB-468", "MFM-223"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You can make it easier for people to help you by sharing the output of ```dput(head(df, 20))```, where df is your data frame.

Comment: I have added output of your suggestion to the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The problem with your request is that the desired output is impossible: data frames only allow for columns of equal length.

Comment: Yeah, I have faced with dimension issue when I try it before. Keeping them in which data structure would be practical ? I was considering lists of lists ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure, because I did not fully understand your desired output...
But here is a go using the `data.table`-package

```
#load library
library(data.table)

#first, create the sample data
#note, rownames are stored in their own column, 'row_name'
dt <- fread("row_name            ABT.263 ABT.869 ABT.888 AC220 Afatinib Afatinib.rescreen.
BT-20          1       1       1     1        0                  1
CAL-120        0       1       1     1        1                  1
CAL-51         1       1       1     1        1                  1
CAL-85-1       1       1       1     1        1                  0
DU-4475        0       1       1     1        1                  1
HCC1143        1       1       1     1        0                  1")

#melt the data to long format, using the 'row_name'-column as identifier
dt.melt <- melt( dt, id.vars = "row_name" )

#now summarise, pasting together row_names by variable-value combination
dt.melt[, .( row = paste0( row_name, collapse = ";" ) ), 
        by = .( value = paste0( variable, "_", value ) ) ]

#                   value                                           row
# 1:            ABT.263_1                 BT-20;CAL-51;CAL-85-1;HCC1143
# 2:            ABT.263_0                               CAL-120;DU-4475
# 3:            ABT.869_1 BT-20;CAL-120;CAL-51;CAL-85-1;DU-4475;HCC1143
# 4:            ABT.888_1 BT-20;CAL-120;CAL-51;CAL-85-1;DU-4475;HCC1143
# 5:              AC220_1 BT-20;CAL-120;CAL-51;CAL-85-1;DU-4475;HCC1143
# 6:           Afatinib_0                                 BT-20;HCC1143
# 7:           Afatinib_1               CAL-120;CAL-51;CAL-85-1;DU-4475
# 8: Afatinib.rescreen._1          BT-20;CAL-120;CAL-51;DU-4475;HCC1143
# 9: Afatinib.rescreen._0                                      CAL-85-1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and brief explanation. I didn't think about melting and reshaping. It worked like a charm for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A base `R` solution with a list of vectors is also possible:

**Code:**

```
names <- names(df)
#
l1 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(df)){
l1[[i]] <- rownames(df)[which(df[,names[i]] == 1)]
}
```

**Result**

```
l1
[[1]]
[1] "BT-20"    "CAL-51"   "CAL-85-1" "HCC1143" 

[[2]]
[1] "BT-20"    "CAL-120"  "CAL-51"   "CAL-85-1" "DU-4475"  "HCC1143" 

[[3]]
[1] "BT-20"    "CAL-120"  "CAL-51"   "CAL-85-1" "DU-4475"  "HCC1143" 

[[4]]
[1] "BT-20"    "CAL-120"  "CAL-51"   "CAL-85-1" "DU-4475"  "HCC1143" 

[[5]]
[1] "CAL-120"  "CAL-51"   "CAL-85-1" "DU-4475" 

[[6]]
[1] "BT-20"   "CAL-120" "CAL-51"  "DU-4475" "HCC1143"
```

This is the list of names with 1 in the `data.frame`, the list of 0's could be obtained identically.